# What is the solution for this quadratic program?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratics, quadratic-forms, quadratic-programming

Given scalars $p_1\geq p_2\geq \cdots \geq p_r > 0$, can we find a solution for following problem?

\begin{align} \text{minimize} & & & \sum_{j=1}^{r} p_j  (1-t_j)^2 \\
\text{s.t.} \\
& & & \forall j:t_j\geq 0 \\
& & & \sum_{j=1}^{r} t_j = 1
\end{align}

> - If finding a solution is impossible in general, which lower bounds we can derive for the objective function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

The function achieves maximum only when the variables $t_i \in \{0, 1\}$ (why?), so $t_r=1$.

---

Added: For the minimum, easiest way seems Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$\left(\sum_{j=1}^rp_j (1-t_j)^2\right)\left( \sum_{j=1}^r \frac1{p_j} \right) \ge \left( r-1\right)^2$$

By the equality condition of CS inequality, for the minimum we need all $\dfrac{p_j(1-t_j)^2}{1/p_j} = p_j^2(1-t_j)^2$ to be the same.  i.e. $p_j(1-t_j) = k$ or $t_j = 1-\dfrac{k}{p_j}$.   We can solve for $k$ using the condition $\sum t_j = 1$, whence $k = \dfrac{r-1}{\sum 1/p_j}$.  Putting all that together, we have
$$\sum p_j (1-t_j)^2 \ge \frac{(r-1)^2}{\sum 1/p_j}$$
with equality iff $t_j = 1-\dfrac{r-1}{p_j \sum 1/p_j}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I had a mistake in the question, it's a minimization problem rather than maximization.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on how to use CS to find $t$?

Comment: Added more detail, hope its clear now.